# Shell script to relay stdin/stdout from an application on one machine to the same application on a different machine

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, netcat

The application, call it '**go-engine-1**' is a Go game engine that runs from a Neural Network. It is really strong and I want to benchmark it on different machines on my network. It is intended to be used with a Go client (e.g. Sabaki or GoGui) that acts as a server to the Go engine. The Go client can be configured to play two local Go engines (e.g. **go-engine-1 vs go-engine-2**) against one another. In my case I want the second engine to run on a different machine. The application uses "Go Text Protocol" (aka gtp for short) to send/receive text based stdin/stdout to/from the Go client. The Go client isn't smart enough to be configured directly with a shell command (like ssh) for the second engine. Gtp is really dumb but the Go engine is smart enough (using gtp as a command line parameter) to remotely send/receive I/O to a shell using ssh. I need the I/O of the network-based Go engine (script) to communicate with the Go client as if it were a stand alone local Go engine.

I am thinking that I can use netcat [/usr/bin/nc] coupled with ssh to create a shell based script for the second engine. As you have likely surmised this is outside my scope of expertise. The script has to be self-contained and appear to the Go client as a local Go engine. So any setting of ports, IP addresses or user accounts would have to be set inside the shell script or referenced from a configuration file. I have configured both machines with ssh-keys so I don't have to send credentials to either machine when logging in or remotely sending commands. If I need to I can set up or configure ports on either (Linux) machine ahead of time as I have root privileges on both machines.

I have tinkered with this and tried things like below for the script to no avail. I have seen similar posts here so I have to believe this is possible and easily realized with the right know-how.
TIA - wirelesstevmc

#!/bin/sh

#/usr/bin/nc remotemachine 22 | /usr/bin/ssh -t user1@remotemachine goengine-2 gtp
/usr/bin/ssh -f -L 9001:127.0.0.1:9000 user1@remotemachine sleep 10
/usr/bin/nc 127.0.0.1 9001 | goengine-1 gtp

Comment: Can the game play against a human, i.e. is it something like chess where you type in moves and the computer prints out moves? One of the examples in the `expect` book has a script relaying moves between two instances of a chess program.

Comment: You can 100% do this with `nc`. Can you edit your question to include the syntax for playing two instances against eachother? Or for how you play human vs. machine. I can imagine that if you play two vs eachother it may be completely internal to the program but if you can play human to machine we can set the machines up so they both act like they would vs a human.

Comment: icarus: Yes the Go engine katago can play against humans and it wins against many professional Go players. You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/lightvector/KataGo#other-questions Go is an ancient board game thought to have been invented by an Ancient Chinese King to teach his son logic. AlphaGo was the first AI program to beat a very high-ranking Korean Professional: Lee Sedol. katago is based on the same software.

Comment: user1794469: You can start the Go engine on a command line with the syntax: $ katago gtp and you can send and receive moves with text commands such as 'play D4'. If you want the engine to respond to your D4 move then on the command line you type gen-move. As you can imagine a Go client such as Sabaki or GoGui which handles all the communication is much better since you get to actually see the pieces which are called stones which is what the Ancient Chinese used as pieces. You of course can do the same thing remotely on another machine with ssh.

Comment: Getting the two engines to pass their output back-n-forth from the command line would be a first step in what I am hoping to do. Ultimately I hope to observe the two engines play each other from the Go client. When configuring the Go client with the engine there are 3 input parameters. 1) Path to engine executable 2) command line parameter. This is always 'gtp' in my case. 3) Time settings which appear in the client as: 'time_settings 0 15 1'. The first two numbers are the time in minutes and seconds allotted per move. The third I believe is the time in minutes per byoyomi period.